# Where are built-in operators defined?

Tags: c++

Where are the operators such as `+` or `-` defined?

E.G. Where can I see the code that says `+` means add two items together?

Was reading through [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) but I must not be seeing the basic `1 + 1 = 2` case in the standard library section. An example of this is shown in the "Additive Operators" section, yet I cant find a location of the function definition.

Comment: _"Where can I see the code that says `+` means add two items together?"_ In the emitted assembly code. It's actually unlclear what you're asking about.

Comment: It's a primitive operations, how would it even be defined? Turtles all the way down?

Comment: @Harold I suppose I thought it had to be given that we can overload the operator with `operator+`. Imagined that the "base" `operator+` had a function that added Left and Right values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler generates the code for these operations - they are not part of the Standard Library. Your compiler will almost certainly have an option to allow you to examine the generated assembly language code.

Comment: So this can be done by the compiler to machine instruction. There isn't necessarily a need to define basic arithmetic operations?

Comment: @pasta The workings of the basic arithmetic operations _are_ defined, in the code of the compiler.

Comment: Is that the same for the `operator` syntax when overloading an operator? I know the Standard Library has some `operator+` defined (and may more), but where is the term `operator` defined such that when the compiler sees "operator" followed by an ASCII value sequence, it overloads it?

Comment: @pasta_sauce Overloading an operator is a completely different thing. Note that you can't overload operators for primitive types at all.

Comment: @pasta You can't overload operators for the built-in types, like ints, doubles and pointers. The keyword `operator` is something  built in to the compiler and, once again, is not part of the Standard Library.

Comment: @NeilButterworth This is excellent! Is this all documented somewhere? Maybe in a good read (don't mind buying a good book about program structures). A good read on primitive operators and operator overloading sounds up my alley right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the language itself... the compiler translate the string "c=a+b;" to add the value stored in a to the value stored in b and set the result to c.

Answer (score 0):

> yet I cant find a location of the function definition.

There might not be a *function definition* at all, but a simple assembly instruction set:

```
mov 1,r1
mov 5,r2
add r1,r2
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there is no `operator+(int,int)`. The addition operator is built-in and no function corresponds to it. In particular, you cannot do this:

```
using intDyadic = int(*)(int, int);
intDyadic add = operator+(int,int);
```

By contrast, you could create a function pointer to an operator override defined in a library, including the standard library.

Comment: I suppose I was trying to determine what "built-in" means. It has to be coded somewhere! And apparently somewhere is in the compiler code.

Comment: @pasta_sauce: That is highly dependent on the implementation. An implementation on minimal hardware which lacks a floating point unit probably includes a library which emulates floating point operations, with the result that the code emitted by the compiler includes calls to these functions. So the functions might exist and might be part of a runtime library (other parts of standard C++ are normally implemented through a library linked with the program.)